# Proof of intersection of perpendicular bisectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

Suppose that $\Delta ABC$ is a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with vertices $A$, $B$ and $C$. Show that the perpendicular bisectors of the sides go through a common point.

I have given position vectors with respect to an origin $O$ of $A(a,b)$, $B(c,d)$, $C(e,f)$ and shown what the vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$ are but I'm now stuck. I think I would need to figure out the position vectors of the midpoints of $BC$ and $AB$ however I don't know how I would do this.

Comment: The midpoint of segment $AB$ is $(A+B)/2.$

Comment: May be this helps:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672721/given-position-vector-of-points-a-b-find-the-equation-of-perpendicular-bisecto

Comment: As example for midpoint - find the vector from A to B and add half of it to A